# PIVOT QUERY in Procedure with new ALIAS NAME as Column Name in Snowflake Datawarehouse

Tags: pivot, alias, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I Include the below query in an Insert with Select, since the Query is included in double quotes

```
"insert into emp_sales(emp_id,JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH,APRIL)
select 
    empid as emp_id,
    "'JAN'" as january,
    "'FEB'" as february,
    "'MAR'" as march,
    "'APR'" as april
  from monthly_sales
    pivot(sum(amount) for month in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR')) 
      as p
  order by empid;"
```

If i include in procedure and try to execute, its giving exception/error due to this "'MAR'" due to this alias, how can I escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Snowflake stored procedure you can escape the quotes with backslashes, since the SQL is in a javascript string literal:

```
create or replace procedure p2() 
returns text
language javascript
as
  $$
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "insert into emp_sales(emp_id,JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH,APRIL) select empid as emp_id, \"'JAN'\" as january, \"'FEB'\" as february, \"'MAR'\" as march, \"'APR'\" as april from monthly_sales pivot(sum(amount) for month in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR')) as p order by empid" } );
  var rs = stmt.execute()
  return 'SUCCESS'
  $$
;
```

Or you can reference the columns by number - a little cleaner:

```
create or replace procedure p1() 
returns text
language javascript
as
  $$
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: "insert into emp_sales(emp_id,JANUARY,FEBRUARY,MARCH,APRIL) select empid as emp_id, $2 as january, $3 as february, $4 as march, $5 as april from monthly_sales pivot(sum(amount) for month in ('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR')) as p order by empid" } );
  var rs = stmt.execute()
  return 'SUCCESS'
  $$
;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, I believe that you can just remove the double quotes around "'MAR'" and go with 'MAR' just like you have in the pivot statement.

In the javascript for a procedure you can also use a backslash (\) to escape quotes: \"'MAR'\"